# HTML Custom Made Menu Control issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, html-lists

I am having a menu as shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gk_999/mtfhptwo/3

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.menumaker = function (options) {

        var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
            title: "Menu",
            format: "dropdown",
            sticky: false
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
            $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
                var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
                if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
                    mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
                }
                else {
                    mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
                    if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                        mainmenu.find('ul').show();
                    }
                }
            });

            cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

            multiTg = function () {
                cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
                cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
                    if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                        $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
                    }
                });
            };

            if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
            else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

            if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

            resizeFix = function () {
                if ($(window).width() > 768) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').show();
                }

                if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
                }
            };
            resizeFix();
            return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

        });
    };
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
            title: "Menu",
            format: "multitoggle"
        });


    });
})(jQuery);
```

Now, in jsFiddle, since the menu is responsive, is working fine. 
However, if we run it on full screen, upon hover on the parent li list, its children appears compulsorily on the right as shown below.

The problem is that, if we have too many elements in the parent list, & if we hover on the elements at extreme right, its children appear compulsorily on right, & move out of the screen window, as a result, a horizontal scroll-bar appears.

[image: Screen 2]

So I want to get the children on the left, rather than right when they are moving out of the screen.

**EDIT:**
Check fullscreen output here : https://jsfiddle.net/Gk_999/mtfhptwo/3/embedded/result/

Any Help...???

Comment: I'm not convinced that your fiddle is working fine. You have issues with overlapping on the menu too.

http://s3.postimg.org/kivjhiimr/Untitled.png

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. Check my edit too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done with JavaScript is my guess.

Update your ready function with the following `mouseenter` event. It will fire when somebody moves the mouse over an `li` with `has-sub` class.

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "multitoggle"
    });

    $("li.has-sub").on("mouseenter", function(){

        var element = this).find("ul");
        //remove the class beforehand so it always defaults to the right.
        $(element.removeClass("showleft");

        //if the rendered menu and it's page offset are wider then the body 
        if (element.offsetWidth + element.offset().left > document.body.offsetWidth)
        {
            element.addClass("showleft");
        }

    });

});
```

Add this to the css:

```
.showleft {
    left : -230px !important;    
}
```

It works, look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mtfhptwo/4/

Answer (score 0):

First, do one thing, get the width of the document using java script and your sub div, set min width of generating  div on hover of sub menu if it is greater than minimum height than animate your sub menu(sub div) to wherever you want or you can also give style using java script css property.